# How was RedBeard not found?

Tags: plot-explanation, sherlock

In the series 4 finally of BBC's *Sherlock*, we learn that

> Sherlock & Mycroft's sister Eurus apparently killed Sherlock's dog, RedBeard, and hid his body where no one would find it.

Later in the episode, we learn that

> RedBeard was actually Sherlock's best friend, not a dog, and that he was buried in a well on the family's property.

Given that, how is it possible that

> no one found RedBeard?
>   Wouldn't the search have been rather exhaustive, and wouldn't that have been one of the first places everyone would look?

Comment: Please use spoilers properly, there are some who haven't watched the episode yet.

Comment: @ABcDexter  The parts I didn't tag as spoilers were the set up to the plot, revealed in the first few moments of the show.

Comment: +1 for your query. Redbeard is not a dog in reality; how come his parents/relatives didn't extensively look for him.

Answer (score 3):

No answer has been given within the show. However, this is possible if

> the well was not located on the Musgrave estate grounds, but in a more remote location. Potentially, it could be an abandoned well known only to children playing around.

This is purely speculation, though.